# Testing multiple services in Integration Tests?

Tags: testing, integration-testing

I know Integration tests are supposed to test multiple components working together, but is it fine to test behavior of one component(which has side-effects) using an unrelated component.

So, I have one microservice (Service A) which fetches data, does some processing and put it in another data store. (Basically, its task is to load the data in the DB)

There is another microservice (Service B) written to perform transactional queries on the data store.

Now while writing integration tests for Service A, is it fine that I use the read operations of Service B to verify that the data has loaded correctly?
By the way Service A does not use Service B to load the data into the data store.

I think that it will increase the coupling between the two services but at the same time directly querying the databases has its own challenges (integrating test environment with the database).